# Is there a way to close a particular instance of explorer with C#?

Tags: c#, process

I'm looking for a way to close a Windows explorer window that's open to a certain folder. Say c:\users\bob\folder. I can close all explorers with the code below, but this is obviously not what I want to do. Is this possible?

```
 foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
 {
    p.Kill();
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you open this explorer yourself? If so, you can just hold onto the process id.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This article that got me most of the way there: http://omegacoder.com/?p=63

I found a way using a COM library called "Microsoft Internet Controls" that looks more intended for Internet Explorer, but I gave up trying to use the process ID's and `MainWindowTitle` stuff since explorer.exe only uses one process for all open windows and I couldn't pin down how to get the window title text or file system location from that.

So first, add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls from the COM tab, then:

```
using SHDocVw;
```

This little routine did the trick for me:

```
ShellWindows _shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
string processType;

foreach (InternetExplorer ie in _shellWindows)
{
    //this parses the name of the process
    processType = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();

    //this could also be used for IE windows with processType of "iexplore"
    if (processType.Equals("explorer") && ie.LocationURL.Contains(@"C:/Users/Bob"))
        {
            ie.Quit();
        }    
}
```

One caveat, and probably owing to the fact this library is geared toward IE, is you have to use forward slashes in your folder path...  That's because the true `LocationURL` that comes back from the `ie` object is in the form `file:///C:/Users/...`

Comment: Hey thats pretty clever. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!  I like that you could use it for IE windows as well...  I'm thinking a manager walk-over panic button? ;)

Comment: I might be late to this party, but this helped me a lot and saved me so much more useless research time, so I have to thank you personally :)

Answer (score 2):

I would try importing user32.dll and calling FindWindow or FindWindowByCaption, followed by a call to DestroyWindow.

Info about FindWindow is here:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow

Answer (score 1):

This works.  It's a follow up on Jeff Roe's post.

```
// Find window by Caption only. Note you must pass IntPtr.Zero as the first parameter.
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

// caption is the window title.
public void CloseWindowsExplorer(string caption)
{
    IntPtr i = User32.FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, caption);
    if (i.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) == false)
    {
        // WM_CLOSE is 0x0010
        IntPtr result = User32.SendMessage(i, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
{
    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("YourFolderName"))
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see one process for multiple explorer instances in Windows 7, and the title is blank.

Comment: This does not work.  It is also mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935271/how-to-close-a-particular-windows-explorer-window-in-c)