# how to close the directory in the given file path using c#

Tags: c#, process, directory

how to check whether the directory in a given path is open or not.. if it is in open then how to close it..
when i trying to delete and recreate the directory and am getting the below error when my **PreviewSerialization** directory is in open state. the exception is thrown at `Directory.Delete` method

```
if (Directory.Exists(filepath))
        {             
            Directory.Delete(filepath, true);              
        }          
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
```

`Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\surya.panchanathan\AppData\Roaming\take123\DD\1.0.0.0\**PreviewSerialization\'`.**

TIA

Comment: Surya : It would be better if you include the code that you are trying

Comment: Sounds like the duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463639/is-there-a-way-to-close-a-particular-instance-of-explorer-with-c)